# Firestore not updating values in embedded collections

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, datastore

Here is parent node
[image: parent structure]

Inside I have clients

[image]

I'm trying to update the lastName of the first client.
[image]

I have the correct ID's, I've checked multiple times. I'm using JAVA, here is the code:

```
public void updateClient(ClientDto client) {
    if(client.getUserId() == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("userId cannot be null when" +
                " updating a client");
    }

    final ClientDto clientById = this.getClientById(client.getClientId(),client.getUserId());

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("name", client.getName());
    data.put("lastName", client.getLastName());
    data.put("middleName", client.getMiddleName());
    data.put("email", client.getEmail());
    data.put("phone", client.getPhone());
    data.put("lastUpdatedBy", client.getLastUpdatedBy());
    data.put("lastUpdatedDate", client.getLastUpdatedDate());

    this.fireDao.getDb()
            .collection("users").document(client.getUserId())
            .collection("clients")
            .document(client.getClientId()).update(data);
}
```

`this.fireDao.getDb()` is an instance of firestore and I'm able to preform all other operations.

Comment: I guess some of the images did not post. I'm using the firestore emulator on a mac. I have  4 fake clients in the clients collection. I'm trying to update the fields described above for the first one.

Comment: Not getting errors but the updates are not happening. I'm able to update fields from other collection like users but I have no idea why the client updates are not taking. I wish it got some sort of error.

Comment: Your code looks like it's correct, so I would say that the problem in likely to be in your data values, if you log the value of data, does it have the values you expect it to have?

Comment: Yes the data logs correctly. Are there any issues with the emulator I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked:

```
    final ApiFuture<WriteResult> update = this.fireDao.getDb().collection("users").document(client.getUserId())
            .collection("clients")
            .document(client.getClientId()).update(data);

    try {
        log.info(format(
                "Updating userId %s for customer id %s at time %s",
                client.getUserId(),
                client.getClientId(),
                update.get().getUpdateTime()));
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        log.error(format(
                "Error updating userId %s for customer id %s",
                client.getUserId(),
                client.getClientId()), e);
    }
```

I think this line did it but I'm not sure why I need it:

**update.get().getUpdateTime()**